# Callback or setState when path is loaded

Tags: reactjs

im trying to find an event or a function, that run everytime i loaded a component, i didn't want `componentDidMount` because it only get triggered once at the initial render, what i want is an event that run everytime the component gets rendered.i want to do this, because, i want to print an updated version of an array, but i need to use `setState` to trigger the `re-rendering`, is there any event or function that runs like this ?, i tried combining `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` but it just gave me an infinite loop

this is my home class to print the array :

```
export class Home extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = ({refresh: false})
    this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this)
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/home">
      <div className="konten container-sm col-sm-10" >
      <body>
        <br></br><br></br>
        <div className="tabel card rounded">
          <div className="card-body">
          <p className="head panel-body">User List</p>
          <input type="text" className="search form-control col-sm-2" placeholder="Search user here">
          </input>
          <Link to="/add"><a href="" className="tambah btn" onClick={this.add}>Add User</a></Link>
          <br/>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Nama</th>
                  <th scope="col">Username</th>
                  <th scope="col">Email</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {user_list.map(user => 
              {
              return(
            <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td>{user.nama}</td>
              <td>{user.username}</td>
              <td>{user.email}</td>
              <td><button className="edit btn">Edit</button></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
              )
              }
              )}            
          </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        </body>
      </div>

      </Route>
      <Route path="/add">
          <Tambah />
      </Route>
      </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

and here is my add class, to input a new data to the array :

```
save(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  user_list.push({
    nama: this.state.nama , 
    username: "John Doe",
    email: this.state.company,
    admin: this.state.admin,
    status: this.state.active})
    console.log(user_list)
    this.setState({createNew: true})
}
```

note that this two code that i just posted is inside a different class, and i create a new data inside the array using `push` method, and when i get back to the home page, the data is not updated until i `re-render` the state, the question is, is there any function that can `re-render` every time i entered the home path ?
any help will be appreciated, thanks before

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: oh ok, i will update my question to make it more clear sorry

Comment: i updated my question, is it more clear now ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're passing a prop down and storing it in state, and you want to update the state everytime new props get passed? one thing you can do is just remove it from your local state and just go based off the prop. ps: updating state won't work in `componentDidUpdate` without a conditional because that would trigger it again which leads to the infinite loop

Comment: im not storing the data inside a state, i store it in an array

Comment: @LuthfiMusafa can you post your code?

Comment: ok i will post it, wait

Comment: in Home where is it getting `user_list` from? basically you need to pass it down as a prop or store in a central area like context/redux, that way when it changes it will automatically trigger a re-render

Answer (score 0):

Use `useEffect` [without dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) it help's you

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: wait, can i use this `useEffect` in a class ? isn't `useEffect` is for functional only ?

Comment: no, you can't use it in a class. you can only use hooks in functional components

Answer (score 0):

If your function is dependent on the new props you'll be receiving from the parent that will render the component then you can use componentWillRecieveProps lifecycle. But if your re-render component is not dependent on the parent then you can simple add the array in you render and it will change on you re-render which will be base on the state.

Comment: Also you should maintain a state for storing the user_list and perform operation on it (push or pop)